# Can I only show the star ratings in app review (excluding the message part)?

Tags: android

When looking at the In-app review for Android (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) it seems like you can show only the star-part (the left most image in the url above). But I can't find anyway to control this. Is it possible? The library hasn't got any properties or anything I can configure it seems like.

Also, the second view from the left (in the url above) suggests that the message is optional. But when implementing this shows that it is required. [image]

I would preferably only show the stars, but if that is not possible the message should be optional.

Is this possible?